# Formatting bibliography: biblio entry followed by page number(s) where the entry is cited. How?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, back-referencing

I'm trying to format a bibliography for a journal submission, and they have the requirement that each bibliography entry is followed by "the page numbers of your manuscript in which these references are cited," . For instance:

> SMITH, John, T. (1966): The Theory of Social Science. Ulan Bator: Famous University
>   Press. [2,3]

Here 2 and 3 would be the pages in my manuscript, where this book is cited. I'm using `natbib`.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe the ``natbib`` package itself has such an option (didn't check that) but there is a package called ``backref```providing exactly this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation of `natbib` says, you should either use package `citeref` (loaded after `natbib`), or package `hyperref` with the `pagebackref` option (always loaded last).

Comment: Awesome, thanks to both ! Both solutions work. For anyone who might be also trying this: citeref looks a bit better imho, with brackets around the page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which uses `biblatex`. In the code, option `backref = true` enables printing back reference, and `backrefstyle = three` instructs the program to compress any sequence of three or more consecutive pages to a range.

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks = false, pdfborderstyle ={/S/D}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none, maxnames = 3, minnames = 2, backref = true, backrefstyle = three, arxiv = abs, doi = true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biber.bib}
@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross section in $p p$ collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 2.76 \mathrm{TeV}$ and comparison to the inclusive jet cross section at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using the ATLAS detector},
journal = {The European Physical Journal C},
year = {2013},
month = {August},
volume = {73},
number = {2509},
doi = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-013-2509-4},
}

@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
month = {February},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
volume = {02},
number = {153},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biber.bib}

\begin{document}

Let us cite \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet} on first page.

\newpage

Then cite \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet} on second page.

\newpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

this is what it produced

[image: page number]